# How does 'pass variable by reference' work?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

code like:

```
// 'type' here indicates certain variable type, int, char, struct, etc.
void foo(type &a, type b) {...}
type a = ...;
type b = ...;
type &c = a;
foo(a, b);
foo(c, b);
```

compiles with no problem. But literally the first parameter of `foo` is of `type&` which is a reference, and `foo(c, b)` looks more consistent to me than `foo(a, b)`, because `c` is a reference `type&` itself but `a` only a `type` variable.

For example say `void bar(int*)` and `int *a; int b` one can only pass `a` to `bar` not `b` due to different parameter type.

What's the underneath mechanism of such inconsistency in pass by reference case?

Comment: Look at it this way, you can write `type &c = a;`, so why would you expect `type &a = a;` to not work in the function declaration?

Comment: @user657267 `type &a = a;` - what?

Comment: @MattMcNabb What I'm trying to say is that if you treat function arguments as just another local variable declaration it should be obvious why this works, OP clearly understands how `type &c = a;` works, binding the `a` declared below `foo` with `foo`'s argument `a` is no different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the declaration of a variable with its usage.

After:

```
type a = x;
type &c = a;
```

the situation is exactly the same as if you had written:

```
type c = x;
type &a = c;
```

In both cases there is one variable and it has two names, `a` and `c`.

<sup>Since C++11 there is one difference, `decltype(a)` will pick up the reference as part of the type</sup>

When you use `a` or `c` in an expression thereafter, it refers to that variable.

When you have `void foo(type &p, type q)`  (changed names to avoid confusion), then if you call `foo(a, b);`, then the name `p` becomes another name for the argument `a`. There is one object with two names, `a` (visible to caller) and `p` (visible in the function).

This latter case is usually implemented by compilers in the same way that passing by pointer is implemented (but implementation details are not something you should take into account when forming a mental model of what something means).

Answer (score 1):

A reference is typically implemented as just a pointer to a memory address.  Assigning a variable to a reference assigns the memory address of the variable.  Assigning a reference to a reference copies the memory address.  If you think of a reference as a pointer (which it logically is, just with extra compiler-enforced restrictions), your example code is essentially doing the following:

```
void foo(type *a, type b) {...}

type a = ...;
type b = ...;
type *c = &a;
foo(&a, b);
foo(c, b);
```

Comment: A reference isn't a memory address. References might not require storage at all (see [dcl.ref]/4).  A reference is another name for an object.

Comment: That might be how the standard language defines in, but it is usually implemented as a pointer in most commonly used compilers.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `a` is of type `type` and so is `b`. `c` is of type `type&`.

When you call the function by passing `a` as the first argument, it grabs a reference to your copy of `a`. When you call it with `c` as an argument, since `c` is already a reference it doesn't have to *reference* that because it's already a reference.

References used to have some differences, but nowadays are primary just a more convenient syntax than pointers. Using pointers, your example looks like:

```
void foo(type *a,type b) {...}
type a = ...;
type b = ...;
type *c = &a;
foo(&a, b); // the compiler is really doing this for you when you use references
foo(c, b);
```

The *only* difference *(on modern compilers)* is that the compiler does the referencing and dereferencing for you and doesn't let the pointer be null *(unless you do creative things, which you won't be doing)*.

In case it helps to think about it linguistically, your function is saying "please give me a reference to a `type` instance and a copy of a `type` instance."

Your first call is saying "here, grab a reference to this `type` instance, and here's a copy of this other `type` instance."

Your second call is saying "here, grab this reference to a `type` instance, and here's a copy of this other `type` instance."